# cygwin: "fmemopen" was not declared in this scope

Tags: cygwin, scip

I am using cygwin to run SCIP under Windows. However, when I use `make` to run the installation, cygwin reports

> "fmemopen" was not declared in this scope
>
> tmpStream = fmemopen(tmpString, 63, "w");

I think the problem arised when I tried to install packages for ZLIB within the cygwin package manager, but I am not sure how I can handle with that error?

Comment: what is the full command line passed to gcc ?  fmemopen is protected in `stdio.h` by `__POSIX_VISIBLE >= 200809`  see `/usr/include/sys/features.h` for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, for some reason the flags `_WIN32` or `_WIN64` is not set when using cygwin. You can do that manually be adjusting the corresponding sub-makefiles `make.cygwin.x86.gnu` or `make.cygwin.x86_64.gnu` in `soplex-2.2.1/make/`:

Simply add `-D_WIN32` or `-D_WIN64`, respectively,  in the first line, extending the `CPPFLAGS` parameter.

You might also try compiling without the rational solving capabilities of SoPlex by running `make LEGACY=true`.

Comment: I did not completely get what I should do. I found the files mentioned in soplex-2.2.1./make/. How can I add the terms mentioned?

Comment: You edit the file like this: `CPPFLAGS += -m32 -D_WIN32`

Comment: I edited the first line of make.cygwin.x86_64.gnu into "CPPFLAGS += -m64 -D_WIN64 LDFLAGS". However, cygwin now says an error: The rule for the target "scipbinary" failed.

Comment: Please read the entire error output to find what is going wrong.

Comment: It says that the file  make/make.cygwin.x86_64.gnu.opt: No such file or directory within zimpl does not exist what is true. According to the site of scip I tried to duplicate 'make/make.cygwin.x86.gnu.opt' as 'make/make.cygwin.x86_64.gnu.opt'. However, then it says that the chosen CPU does not support the x86-64 commands.

Comment: You may run `make ZIMPL=false` if you don't ZIMPL in your application. This is the easiest way to get rid of these errors.

Comment: adding `-D_WIN32 or -D_WIN64` on cygwin is in general a BAD idea

Comment: Would you please care to enlighten us? Why is this such a bad idea?

Comment: But I will need ZIMPL later on. However first, I tried to install SCIP without ZIMPL where I get the error `gettimeofday was not declared in scope'.

Comment: This discussion won't lead anywhere. There seems to be a structural error. Serious suggestion: use a Linux virtual machine. You will not regret it. Developing open source C/C++ code is a lot easier on Linux.

Comment: I installed SCIP without problems in Ubuntu. Thanks for your patience.